# Link child product to parent product when not contained in child element

Tags: html5, microdata

I'm trying to indicate multiple related products on a product page using Microdata (with Schema.org). But the child products are orphaned because they are not contained in the parent `div`. I tried using `itemref` but I must be using it incorrectly or it must be the wrong solution.

Also, I cannot easily create a wrapper `div` or use the `body` element to create the parent.

My ideal solution would be one that leaves the page structure as-is, and somehow links the "child product" `div`s to the parent. I thought `itemref` would do that, but it doesn't appear to be working.

Here is example HTML.

```html
<div id="main-product" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

  <div class="product-name">
      <h1 itemprop="name">Main Product</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END main-product div -->
<!-- START related-products div -->
<div class="related-products">
<ol class="products-list" id="related-products-list">
  <li class="item">
    <div class="product" itemprop="isRelatedTo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemref="main-product">
      <p class="product-name"><a itemprop="url" href="/some_product1.php"><span itemprop="name">Some Product 1</span></a></p>                
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="product" itemprop="isRelatedTo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemref="main-product">
      <p class="product-name"><a itemprop="url" href="/some_product2.php"><span itemprop="name">Some Product 2</span></a></p>                
    </div>
   </li>
</ol>
</div>
```

The above HTML is simplified, but similar in structure to what's on my site and gives similar errors when submitted to validators.

E.g. http://webmaster.yandex.com/microtest.xml gives:

```
microdata
ERROR: unable to determine affiliation of these fields. There are two possible reasons: this fields are incorrectly placed or an orphan itemprop attribute is indicated
itemType = orphans
isrelatedto
product
itemType = http://schema.org/Product
url
href = /some_product1.php
text = Some Product 1
name = Some Product 1
isrelatedto
product
itemType = http://schema.org/Product
url
href = /some_product2.php
text = Some Product 2
name = Some Product 2

product
itemType = http://schema.org/Product
name = Main Product
```

The [Google validator](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:8004ecc4050e256c9b52a383b5bb5874) does not seem to show any errors, but the child products are not related to the parent product.

Answer (score 1):

It may pass Google but there is still problems with the code. To resolve the issue with Yandex, W3C and to be sure that it works well on all engines, all platforms and browsers then you should resolve this problem. The problem is that you are closing the product div early which results in `The itemprop attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item`.

Simply add a wrapper, or attach it too the body or html for example:

```
<div class="product-wrapper" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<div id="main-product">
```

OR

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<div id="main-product">
```

So your going to need to change your HTML code to make it validate, simples.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I cannot create a wrapper or use `body`. The `body` is created before the system knows whether this is a product page or a catalog page. The main product part of the page is created by a different module than the related products. I will dig deeper and see if there's any way I can create a wrapper. But I was under the impression that `itemref` can be used to link up schema that are in separate divs. Is that not the case?

Comment: I tried it, and do not ned to add to the body. I have the body, some divs, and then the product div. Because we use bootstrap, the girl who made the design of the page, created an affix section outside of the product div. There is the description of the product. I've used this what @unor sad in the other answer, and that works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `itemref` can do this, but it has to be used on the element to which the properties should be added to.

So instead of this

```html
<div id="main-product" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
</div>

<div itemref="main-product" itemprop="isRelatedTo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
</div>
```

you have to use this

```html
<div itemref="related-product-1" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
</div>

<div id="related-product-1" itemprop="isRelatedTo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
</div>
```

Comment: Works great. Schema validator and w3 validator is good with it. I used it for description, but description is outside of the product, but description is appears at the validator. Thank you! This should be the accepted solution. The question is, what happens, when you need to add more and more elements?

Comment: @karacsi_maci: The `itemref` attribute can take multiple ID values, separated by space: `itemref="related-product-1 related-product-2 related-product-3"`.